# Python function to create save and load dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, csv

Hello everyone I am writing a function to contact several csv files into one. Then save it as a master cover file and finally I want to load the df but when I call the function and try to call the df it is called as none type.
Here's what i use:

```
    def create_excel():
        import pandas as pd
        import os 
        import numpy as np
        import glob
        from datetime import date , timedelta
        yesterday=date.today() - timedelta(1)
        file_name=yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        file=file_name+'.csv'
        path=input('Enter path :')
        csv=sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.csv')))
        df_from_csv=(pd.read_csv(f,error_bad_lines=False)for f in csv)
        login_history=pd.concat(df_from_csv,ignore_index=True)
        return login_history.to_csv(file)
        return login_history

create_excel()
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should move imports up before the def body. And use 1 return.

Comment: You have 2 return statements

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import os 
    import numpy as np
    import glob
    from datetime import date , timedelta

def create_excel():
    yesterday=date.today() - timedelta(1)
    file_name=yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    file=file_name+'.csv'
    path=input('Enter path :')
    csv=sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.csv')))
    df_from_csv=(pd.read_csv(f,error_bad_lines=False)for f in csv)
    login_history=pd.append(df_from_csv,ignore_index=True)
    login_history.to_csv(file)
    return login_history

create_excel()
```

I have:

1. moved the import out of the def
2. the to_csv should not be with return
3. change concat to append

Comment: Why the change from concat to append?

Comment: My preference - you can use both

Comment: I see, but isn't the first `df_from_csv` a  tuple? Is it possible to append pd.DataFrame object to tuples?

Comment: I see what i did wrong , but my problem is that after calling the function and then try to call the csv file after i called the function i get an error 'login_history' is not defined.

Comment: happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 return statements. A function will always stop once it reaches a return statement. None was returned because: `login_history.to_csv(file)` writes to a file, but does not return anything at all -> `None`. Since you used return for that, you own function will return `None` and stops the function.

The fix is therefore rather simple:

```
def create_excel():
    # your code [...]
    login_history.to_csv(file)
    return login_history

login_history = create_excel()
```

Comment: I see what i did wrong , but my problem is that after calling the function and then try to call the csv file after i called the function i get an error 'login_history' is not defined.

Comment: ah, yes because you then need to set the variable name outside the function. The function variables will be "forgotten" -> clear up memory, after usage. So you can then get the login history like this: `login_history = create_excel()`, updated my answer acordingly

Comment: O ok , worked for me , just had to store the function in a value as you mentioned....Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @GeorgePapadopoulos, Gald I could help! Please consider to accept and upvot the answer if it was helpful. It will help future readers to see this question was answered and gives me a few points. Happy coding!